# Rails active record association with join example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to get the hang on using associations. I have been following the RailsGuides, but no lightbulbs. I am able to accomplish what I want, but I rather want it to be more elegantly. Right now, I am doing three activerecord lookups, while I think a simple join would be more efficient. Using the .join method ends up in error messages, so I ask here for some help finding the light switch. I am using Rails **4.1.6**

The models:

```
# models

class Chicken < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cage

  # id, name, age
end

class Cage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chicken
  belongs_to :farm

  # id, cage_number, rack, chicken_id, farm_id
end 

class Farm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cages

  # id, city
end
```

The controller:

```
# controller

def display
@the_chicken = Chicken.find_by_name("Alfred")
@the_cage = Cage.find_by_chicken_id(@the_chicken.id)
@the_farm = Farm.find(@the_cage.farm_id)
end
```

the view:

```
<%= @the_chicken.name %>
<%= @the_chicken.age %>
<%= @the_cage.rack +  ": " + the_cage.cage_number %>
<%= @the_farm.city %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The find_by_xxx I think is deprecated in Rails 4.x. You should use something like this: @the_chicken = Chicken.find_by(name: 'Alfred')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see any reason to use join in what you say, but you should leverage you associations though:

```
@the_chicken = Chicken.find_by(name: "Alfred")
@the_cage = @the_chicken.cage
@the_farm = @the_chicken.farm
```

I feel like you'd like to eager load your data which you can do using `includes`. This is useful when you fetch collection of chickens to avoid N+1.

If you do `Chicken.includes(:cage, :farm).find_by_name("Alfred")` you'd still have 3 queries

Answer (score 2):

In your display method you can use association like this :

```
def display
  @the_chicken = Chicken.find_by_name("Alfred")
  @the_cage = @the_chicken.cage
  @the_farm = @the_cage.farm
end
```

One more thing you don't have @ in your view. It must be an typo. So it should be like

```
<%= @the_chicken.name %>
<%= @the_chicken.age %>
<%= @the_cage.rack +  ": " + @the_cage.cage_number %>
<%= @the_farm.city %>
```

You should also have one association between chicken and farm.

```
class Chicken < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cage
  belongs_to :farm, through :cage
  # id, name, age
end

class Cage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chicken
  belongs_to :farm

  # id, cage_number, rack, chicken_id, farm_id
end 

class Farm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cages
  has_many :chickens, through :cage
  # id, city
end
```

So you can directly find farm from chicken.

```
@the_farm = @the_chicken.farm
```

Comment: Indeed typo's with the instance vars! Isn't this like a cross reference table using the :through parameter? According to the RailsGuides I have to build that table with a migration using the DSL? Or am I, as always wrong?

Comment: can't get you sorry! can you please more specific.